# Affinity Photo Crashing - CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error

Tags: crash, font, font-book

Just bought Affinity Photo for my Mac Mini running Yosemite. Cannot open a psd stating it cannot be parsed. and I either see this

```
7/10/15 3:01:42.190 PM Affinity Photo[8306]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFFFFFFFFFECC) from font server
```

in the console or this error below:

```
7/10/15 2:43:16.968 PM Affinity Photo[7984]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: NSFont)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89eb003c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff93f6276e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89d96c66 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 1174
    3   libcocoaui                          0x00000001080614ae -[FontFamilyPopUpButton addFontItems] + 494
    4   libcocoaui                          0x0000000107b1f1c1 -[AppController resetFontCache] + 33
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89e6c45c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89d5c634 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff961339d1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89dcc8ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89dbe9f5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89dbe1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89dbdbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff87ad856f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
    13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff87ad82ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
    14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff87ad812b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b3398ab _DPSNextEvent + 978
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b338e58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b504887 -[NSApplication _realDoModalLoop:peek:] + 666
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b500e76 -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] + 119
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b6d61e3 _NXDoLocalRunAlertPanel + 425
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b6d6020 NSRunAlertPanel + 159
    21  libcocoaui                          0x000000010813e081 -[NotificationsController handleOpenDocumentFailedNotification:] + 1825
    22  libcocoaui                          0x000000010813a448 -[NotificationsController handleNotification:] + 1640
    23  libcocoaui                          0x0000000108139b38 -[NotificationsController receiveNotification:] + 1096
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff965d4323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff965cfc13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff965dbcbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 861
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89e033f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89dbe68f __CFRunLoopRun + 2159
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89dbdbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    30  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff87ad856f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
    31  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff87ad82ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
    32  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff87ad812b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    33  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b3398ab _DPSNextEvent + 978
    34  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b338e58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
    35  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b32eaf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
    36  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b2ab244 NSApplicationMain + 1832
    37  Affinity Photo                      0x00000001072c4574 Affinity Photo + 9588
)
```

Seems to be related to a font issue and [Apple NSFONT](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFont_Class/index.html). I removed all fonts causing errors and restored default fonts, restarted Affinity and still I am getting:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/psd-in-question.psd

The file could not be parsed.
```

I added my comment to a ticket with Affinity [here](https://affinity.serif.com/forum/index.php?/topic/10184-affinity-photo-quit-unexpectedly/), but it seems to be moderated for now as I posted the first time. I also am not missing Helvetica or Helvetica Neue as some said could cause the issue at the Affinity Photo Forum. And I removed the old beta plist as suggested in other Apple threads related to my issue:

```
com.seriflabs.affinityphoto.beta.LSSharedFileList.plist
```

from `/Users/me/Library/Preferences`

Been following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072741/coretext-copyfontsforrequest-received-mig-ipc-error for clues. Could be related to a Chromium issue mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=452894), but have not been able to debug this issue in particular. And frankly tough for me to deal with.

Has anybody had this issue or this type of issue before and a solution?

Comment: Following https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5503208?tstart=0 I deleted the savedState data of com.seriflabs.affinityphoto and restarted and tried app again, but no joy.

Comment: Another psd for which I was missing several fonts did open without any issues. So it does not mean there is an issue with a missing font it seems..

Comment: A developer with Affinity Photo has replied here https://affinity.serif.com/forum/index.php?/topic/1819-failed-to-open-psd-file-the-file-could-not-be-parsed/ saying the parsing issue has to do with the file tagging done by Photoshop and not the error I mentioned. Will send them a file to see if they can reproduce the error so I can open the file as soon as I can. The error causing the mentioned crash still remains though.

Comment: reproducing the issue with another file made by the same CC Photoshop version is not working as of yet..